# How to serialize ChoiceFields in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

First time Python user here, coming from Javascript world. I'm able to retrieve my Model serialized to JSON from Django API and display it on the frontend written in React. But now I just added one more field `priority` to the Model that has multiple choices and I struggle to get these choices to the frontend (I want to display them in a dropdown and update REST API). Migration was successful and I can select choices from the back end but on the frontend I just get the default value set from migrations. Here is my code right now:

models.py

```
class Todo(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  description = models.TextField()
  completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  priority_choices = [
    ('High', 'High'),
    ('Medium', 'Medium'),
    ('Low', 'Low'),
  ]
  priority= models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=priority_choices, default='Low') #new field

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Todo

      
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Todo
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'completed', 'priority')
```

views.py

```
class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):     
  serializer_class = TodoSerializer          
  queryset = Todo.objects.all()
```

I just want the simplest solution, preferably to just update `TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)` class inside serializers.py so that it would all come from this one Model. Is that possible? Reading https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choicefield is not clear for me whether I need to create a new class for the same Model just to retrieve ChoiceFields or if it's possible to do it all from one Class but whatever I try, I get syntax errors. Like I said, I'm very fresh to Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```py
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    priority_choices = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_priority_choices(self, obj):
        return [choice[0] for choice in Todo.priority_choices]

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'completed', 'priority', 'priority_choices')
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything new. I already have priority working. I need `priority_choices`. I want to access High, Medium, Low from my front-end app. Not just a single value of priority that is set on a record. `fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'completed', 'priority', priority_choices)` is it possible?

Comment: Gotcha. See my edit to accomplish what you want

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to get just a first or second value of all Choices instead of `[High, High], [Low, Low]` without doing any regex or splitting?

Comment: Yeah you can use a list comprehension to easily do this in `get_priority_choices`. Updated my answer to show that